# System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution which contains in each project (Android, iOS and Windows 8.1) a lib called Plugin.SecureStorage from here:
https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage
I installed it via NuGET in each project.

Everything works fine in iOS and Windows 8.1, the problem is in Android. The project in Android builds correctly, however at startup I get this:

```
[...]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
09-27 18:14:49.880 D/Mono    (30329): Assembly Ref addref AppConsume.Droid[0xb8cb0608] -> mscorlib[0xb8c64bc0]: 23
09-27 18:14:49.890 D/Mono    (30329): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xb8cbca58] -> System.Collections[0xb8cc5980]: 3
09-27 18:14:49.900 D/Mono    (30329): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Core[0xb8cbca58] -> System.Threading[0xb8cd4948]: 3
09-27 18:14:49.930 D/Mono    (30329): Assembly Ref addref AppConsume.Droid[0xb8cb0608] -> Plugin.SecureStorage[0xb8cb43f8]: 2
Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019
```

What it does mean? is a bit cryptic to me. How can I resolve this problem?

Of course, as a requirement, I added this line...

```
SecureStorageImplementation.StoragePassword = "mypass";
```

in the MainActivity.cs of the Android project...

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.SecureStorage;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SecureStorageImplementation.StoragePassword = "mypass";
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

I also found that changing the line position throws different 'token types' in the exception.

**UPDATE:** I just found the app runs sucessfully when compiling in **Release Mode**. However, not working in Debug mode is a problem that I would like to fix I don't think that is out of scope of this question.

Comment: After a really poorly executed code merge, I too was getting this error except with token 0100002a but the error would go away when I commented out the namespace wide and/or App class XAMLC annotation. I ended up starting the merge over and the issue went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete solution

1. Install nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/sameerIOTApps.Plugin.SecureStorage/
2. Create **SecureStorageLinkerOverride.cs** in **Droid** project

   ```
   using System;
   using Plugin.SecureStorage;

   namespace MyApp.Droid
   {
       public static class LinkerPreserve
       {
           static LinkerPreserve()
           {
               throw new Exception(typeof(SecureStorageImplementation).FullName);
           }
       }

       public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
      {
      }


   }
   ```
3. Right click on Droid Project -> Property -> Android Option-> Linker -> "SDK Assemblies Only"

Now run your project. Comment bellow for any issues else marked it answer.

Comment: It was on older version of xamarin need to duplicate the error in new version

Answer (score 52):

Same error for me.

**Problem:**

I had different versions of the `Xamarin.Forms` package in my solution.

**Solution:**

Change in your Core, Droid and IOS project the `Xamarin.Forms` versions. Make sure that all versions are the same.

I hope this works.

Comment: This resolved it for me, although it was a mismatch in another cross platform package.  Thanks!

Comment: Voting up, I had a version mismatch between `Xamarin.Forms` and `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` packages on all : Portable, iOS and Android projects.

Comment: Wow, just wow... Somehow in these Shared Project files there exists a link who makes the whole thing break because of not really existing dependencies... Still accurate, you got my vote!

Comment: I'm starting to think Xamarin is not worth the effort for Android. It's quicker to write your app in Android Studio than it is to solve obscure visual studio errors. Also the resulting app takes up less space and is faster. Can't see it being anything more than a temporary solution in the long term.

Comment: Problem still exists today but with iOS. Xamarin.Forms has the newest version in all projects. Happens only on some development machines and iOS devices, I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2015, running the project in **Release Mode** have no issues (if you don't change the default settings)

In **Debug mode** by selecting Linking: **"SDK Assemblies Only"** in Project Properties -> Android Options -> Linker, will run the project without problems.

Or just simply leave those Debug settings and **add a file called "SecureStorageLinkerOverride.cs"** in the Android project:

```
using System;
using Plugin.SecureStorage;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public static class LinkerPreserve
    {
        static LinkerPreserve()
        {
            throw new Exception(typeof(SecureStorageImplementation).FullName);
        }
    }

    public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: where to find Plugin.SecureStorage ?

Comment: Install this package via Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sameerIOTApps.Plugin.SecureStorage/

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that Xamarin.Forms are up to date in the Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS... projects