# Could not resolve type with token 0100000f

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get this error when running `ios` in `xamarin` forms. How can I resolve this?

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000f

```cs
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752764/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000019)

Comment: @jgoldberger but the accepted answer over there isn't right :(

Answer (score 54):

The `TypeLoadException` with a number token (instead of a type name) usually indicates that the assembly used at runtime is different than the one used at compile time.

In the Xamarin.Forms case, that usually means you have different projects in your solution referencing different versions of Xamarin.Forms

make sure all of your projects are aligned in version, and that you do not have stale ones lying around (do a `git clean -xfd`, or remove the `packages` folder, restore the nugets, and make sure there's only one XF version pulled from nuget.org)

Comment: in my case, after follow all your steps, i still need to uninstall my android app manually, after that, Xamarin Studio will show "Synchronising Assemblies.." and issue solved, thx for the direction

Comment: could you please elaborate what you mean by this "make sure all of your projects are aligned in version" ?

Comment: Got this in my upgrade to .NET Core, trying to use FSharp.Data's Http.AsyncRequest. Changed a whole bunch of package versions and boom it builds! Then this. A good clean and all works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Had accidentally added a pre release version of Prism Forms to one project.

Comment: I'm getting this bug in 3.1.0.697729 of Xamarin.Forms. I've gone over and over the projects to make sure they are referencing the same package and done Git cleans again and again. I've inspected the csprojs with text editors, and th NuGet package manager inside Visual Studio. I can't fix this issue.

Comment: This hint also saved me that I had different versions of NuGet packages; I rolled them all to the same version and problem fixed... many thanks!