# Could not resolve type with token 0100004c

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project I'm trying to run in android, it's giving me this error. I was just messing around for 2 minutes trying the following:

```
someEntry.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
```

After this my app crashed while it was working before.

**EDIT: I am aware that this had nothing to do with it but I was desperate to find out what was going on which is why I put this in the explanation.**

I undid all my changes afterwards. Ever since I did that this error occurs on startup:

Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100004c

So I guess my question mostly is, what does this token "0100004c" mean and is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163887/could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000f

Comment: @AlenGenzić  I've seen that, but it isn't my problem

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild. If that doesn't help throw away all the bin and obj folders for each project, then build again.

Comment: Try deleting bin an obj folders and then rebuilding.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thank you very much, Gerald and Alen. That fixed it. Is there anyway you can explain why this happened and why this fixed my problem? I would like to understand what happened, maybe it will help me prevent running into this problem again.

Comment: Added it as an answer with a more extensive explanation, please accept if it helped you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors like this usually mean that the assemblies aren't in sync any more. This means that assemblies, gathered in your `bin` and `obj` folders in the different projects contains mixed versions and thus can cause unexpected behavior. This is already detected while loading and gives a bit cryptic error message, like the one you are seeing.

There are basically two options to resolve this quickly:

1. Try a clean and rebuild on your complete solution
2. If that doesn't work; manually delete the `bin` and `obj` folders from each project folder and rebuild

The exact cause for this is hard to say. Hopefully it was just an incident and from here on out you will be fine. If it happens more often, you probably want to look into the order that your projects are built within your solution and what projects *are* built when you run your executable project. It could happen that a project is built to late, or not being rebuilt at all when running from the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help and explain. Everything is much clearer to me now.

Comment: Where are the bin and obj folder?