# Impossible to use PrestaSharp with new Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prestashop, restsharp

I would like to use [PrestaSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bukimedia.PrestaSharp/) to create a Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS mobile app.
Unfortunately, I encounter many problems and it is impossible for me to contact my prestashop website with PrestaSharp. Could you help me please ?

Here are the steps to reproduce from scratch :

- Run Visual Studio and create a new "Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)" project.
- Choose Blank App, Xamarin.Forms, and Portable Class Library (PCL)
- Open the solution's Nuget Package Manager, and try to install Bukimedia.PrestaSharp on Android and iOS projects.
- Get an error message :

> "Could not install package 'RestSharp 105.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author."

- PrestaSharp depends on RestSharp. So the Nuget Package Manager, search for RestSharp, and install latest version (actually 105.2.3) on Android and iOS projects.
- Compile and deploy your Android app => OK, no problem
- Now install PrestaSharp on Android and iOS project (actually version 1.157.0)
- Compile and deploy your Android app => it does not compile. You get the following error message :

> "Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? Nom de fichier :
>   'System.Configuration.dll'    à
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    à
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    à
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver) EpicuriaSucreSale.Android   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets"

- On your Android project, add a reference to

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll".

Doing that is really bad for production, but it compiles, is enough for a proof of concept, and I didn't find another solution.

- Add a button to your Page, and when the button is clicked, call this code :

  ```
  CartFactory cartFactory = new CartFactory(sYourPrestashopURL, sYourPrestashopAPIKey, sYourPrestashopAPIPassword);
  var tmp = cartFactory.Get(iID);
  ```
- When this code is executed, cartFactory.Get(iID); throw the following exception :

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000056
>   at Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.CartFactory.Get (System.Int64
>   CartId) [0x00017] in :0     at
>   PrestaPOC.Droid.ButtonPresta.GetCartFromID (System.Int32 iID)
>   [0x00016] in
>   C:\Workspace\PrestaPOC\PrestaPOC\PrestaPOC.Android\ButtonPresta.cs:15 
>   at PrestaPOC.MainPage.BtnPresta_Clicked (System.Object sender,
>   System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in
>   C:\Workspace\PrestaPOC\PrestaPOC\PrestaPOC\MainPage.xaml.cs:21     at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.IButtonController.SendClicked ()
>   [0x00020] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Button.cs:125 
>   at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer+ButtonClickListener.OnClick
>   (Android.Views.View v) [0x0000b] in
>   C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\ButtonRenderer.cs:291
>   at
>   Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_
>   (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_v) [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-25/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:1857
>   at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:b3822dae-4195-4828-9258-0b3725f17771
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)

- I googled for that and the exception seems to be throwed because there is two references to a dll but of different version. I am pretty sure it's because of System.Configuration.dll
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511504/4965913
  And here I am, after two entire days working on that POC, I can't get carts from my prestashop website.
  Please I need your help :) What should I do to get it working ? What did I do wrong ?

I put the project on Github so you can get it to reproduce the exception : https://github.com/espritm/PrestaPOC

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: PrestaSharp is a wrapper for their REST apis, it would be fairly easy, to use something like paulcbetts' Refit to provide your own wrapper, I would be surprised if it was wasn't faster to do then your proof of concept app. ;-) http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

Comment: Thank you #SushiHangover ! I will take a look to that library and create my own wrapper :) But it's too bad, the job was already done with that nuget package...

Comment: Maybe if enough people contact their official support and post issue updates to Github they will provide a NetStd-based portable package that can be used within Xamarin, but if you need something "today", using their REST apis can get the job done ;-)