# System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000115

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

> Exception Unhandled.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000115
>   (from typeref, class/assembly
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute, Xamarin.Forms.Core,

**Code:**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

It occurs on the line `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle)`

Comment: Never post images of code. Take minimal effort and copy it into question... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: delete bin and obj folders, clean, rebuild and try again. If it still fails, set your output window to "detailed" and check if you can find more information about the exception there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve type with token 0100000f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163887/could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000f)