Self Signed Cert for SSL/TSL connection issues in C#
I need to connect with a device over SSL and in a library using a self signed certificate.  I have been able to do with in my test enviorment (my machine with a console application) using a CertificateRequest in .NET. When I run this in my production enviorment I get an exception "Could not resolve type with token 0100005e from typeref (expected class 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.CertificateRequest' in assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')". I am assuming this exeption is due to the .NET or C# version running in the test enviorment.  What would be a good alterniteve to CertificateRequest that could be used in this case?
Below is the code I am using that works in my test enviorment but not in my production enviorment.  This is my first run with creating/using certs for communication with API's in C# so this snippit of code is a basic copy of an example I found either on Stack Overflow or another website in searching how to create self signed certs.
internal X509Certificate2 GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(string SubjectName)
{
    try
    {
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(1024))
        {
            var request = new CertificateRequest("CN=Lazlo", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

            request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
                new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(request.PublicKey, false));

            var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(40));

            return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}

Edit- The solution Target Framework is 4.8.
I would love to be able to update the version in my target environment, but I don't have control over that. I have confirmed that my target environment is running 4.7 and have changed my target framework in VS. Is there something I could use in 4.7 to accomplish what I am trying to do, or is there a way to create an X509Certificate2 with bouncy castle? I would rather not re-write the rest of my code using the x509Certificate2 object if I can avoid it.
I genuinely appreciate the opinions on my need to upgrade, but as I have said, I have no control over the ability to upgrade the target environment. Could I please get some advice on pulling this off in 4.7?

CertificateRequest was added in .NET Framework 4.7.2; so if you aren't seeing it in production, you either have a version older than 4.7.2 (which would be older than the 4.8 you're targeting)... or you somehow have a bad copy of System.Core.dll.  I'd solve that problem instead of "what else could I do?"

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511504

I would love to be able to update the version in my target environment but I don't have control over that.  I have now confirmed that my target environment is running 4.7 and have changed my target framework in VS.  Is there something I could use in 4.7 to accomplish what I am trying to do, or is there a way to create an X509Certificate2 with bouncy castle.  I would rather not re-write the rest of my code that is using the x509Certificate2 object if I can avoid it.

Given that .NET Framework 4 can only ever have one minor build version installed, and it updates with the operating system, this indicates you are using an out of date and unsupported system, and should be upgraded ASAP. You are probably missing many security and bug fixes.

I genuinely appreciate the opinions on my need to upgrade, but as I have said, I have no control over the ability to upgrade the target environment. Could I please get some advice on pulling this off in 4.7?
