# Xamarin android project getting system.typeload exception could not resolve type with token 010000cb

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While I am running Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio, I am getting following error:

> system.typeload exception could not resolve type with token 010000cb

I have tried to find out the cause but no luck. Please give me an idea of what is causing this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752764/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000019)

Comment: This is often caused by having different conflicting versions of packages in your project