# Change Xamarin Forms version for each platform - iOS, Android & Shared

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the same error message as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752764/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000019?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, causing my Xamarin Forms project to not deploy. This is because each platform target of my project (iOS, Android and the Shared Platform) is running different versions of Xamarin forms.

The answer in the linked question was:

**Solution:**

**Change in your Core, Droid and IOS project the Xamarin.Forms versions. Make sure that all versions are the same.**

How do I change my Xamarin.Forms versions for each of my target platforms? Here is what my navigation menu looks like:

[image]

Comment: Update all your Xamarin.Forms nuget packages to the same version in all of your projects

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your solution in VS expand the packages folder and right click your Xamarin.Forms package. Each `.csproj` in your `.sln` should be on the same version if not update update it to the version to match that or just update all of them to the latest XF.

[image]

It will look a bit different if you're on windows, which has the nice package manager, so in that case you can right click on your open solution and go to manage nuget packages for solution.

[image]

Comment: I just updated my answer it looks a bit different on Windows